# Use pub global activate --source path from other local dart project

Tags: dart

I am trying [this](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-from-your-path), and it works great for terminal applications to reference `$HOME/.pub-cache/bin`

Can I use an activated local package from other local projects?

Steps:
1. `pub global activate --source path .` From package project
2. Then how to use this in another project `pubspec.yaml` dependencies: section?

I know I can use path, but this is much better for dynamic reference reasons.

If I add this in pubspect.yaml dependencies in the project using cli2 package:

```
dependencies:
  cli2: 0.0.0 # name of: pub global activate --source path .
```

I get this error:

```
Because usecli2 depends on cli2 any which doesn't exist (could not find package cli2 at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.
```

Comment: "If I add this in pubspect.yaml". What has this to do with `pub global activate`?

Comment: Thanks, it is the project using the package. I will rewrite - to make more clear!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pub global activate` is to install Dart scripts from `bin/` of a package as command line executables and is completely unrelated to adding dependencies to a project.

You can use relative paths to add local dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  cli2
    path: ../cli2
```

Comment: So this might be a solution: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pub_server

Comment: Depends on what the problem is. Way easier than setting up a custom `pub_server` would be to commit to GitHub and use a git dependency instead of a path dependency (or run your own Git server).